# JavaScript not working on Windows Server 2003

Tags: javascript, windows

I have compiled my website and tested locally and everything works fine. However, when I upload my script to the host, the js files are not working on the server (Windows 2003). The error message received when executing the script is:

> 'window' is  undefined
>   'navigator' is undefined
>   microsoft jscript runtime error

Please let me know the any testing method to check the js function in windows server.

Regards,
Riyas

Comment: Could you please share some code. There might be an error in it.

Comment: Looks like some other problem than the operation system it is running on...because....js is executed client side.

Comment: Hi Baszz, js is executed client side >> I am not very good at scripting. can you explain me a bit more. I could see the same code works in a other windows server. Since I am facing the mentioned particularly in the server. I have tested jscript, MIME and other but every things seems to be fine.

Comment: @Riyas: please post the relevant code.  It's unclear whether you are targeting a JavaScript environment (e.g. client-side web browser) or JScript (e.g. server-side Windows Scripting Host).  It sounds like you are possibly confusing the two...

Answer (score 2):

Turn off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security for admin users and ensure you're logged in as an admin after that:

Step 1 - Go to: Start-->Control Panel-->Add or Remove Programs-->Add/Remove Windows Components

Step 2 - Highlight (don't uncheck) Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration

Step 3 - Click "Details"

Step 4 - Uncheck "For administrative groups"

Step 5 - Click OK, then close windows setup and add/remove window

Step 6 - Never use that server's browser to access the real internet again :)